# Confusing "instanceof " result

Tags: javascript

```
    function Foo() {}

    function Bar() {}

    Bar.prototype = new Foo()

    console.log("Bar.prototype.constructor === Foo ? " 
     + (Bar.prototype.constructor === Foo))

    console.log("new Bar() instanceof Bar? " 
     + (new Bar() instanceof Bar))
```

```
=> Bar.prototype.constructor === Foo ? true
=> new Bar() instanceof Bar? true
```

Why is the "instanceof" result not "false", because the "constructor" doesn't refer to itself but the inherited prototype?

Comment: Maybe you should read on what actually the `constructor` property refers to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: as a note, you don't need to use string concatenation for `console.log`, it can take multiple arguments, and give you better data if you pass in arguments separately: `console.log('Bar.prototype.constructor === Foo", Bar.prototype.constructor === Foo);`

Comment: the docs for instanceof are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`instanceof` does not use the `constructor` property. It internally calls the `[HasInstance]` method of the function object, which is described in [§15.3.5.3 of the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.3).

It compares the prototype of the object (and the prototype of the prototype of the object, etc) with the `prototype` property of the function.

A similar implementation would be:

```
function myInstanceOf(obj, Constr) {
    // get prototype of object
    var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);

    // climb up the prototype chain as long as we don't have a match
    while (proto !==  Constr.prototype && proto !== null) {
        proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
    }

    return proto === Constr.prototype;
}
```

As far as I know, the `constructor` property is not used by any internal methods, only by user generated code.

Comment: Concise & concrete! Does MDN write so legibly? There's minor typo for inspecting the prototype chain upwards, i.e. `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) === objCtor.prototype` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bar.prototype = new Foo()
```

therefore

```
Bar.prototype instanceof Foo
```

therefore

```
Bar.prototype.contructor === Foo
```

Constructor returns a reference to the actual function

**Instanceof**

The difference between instanceof and the constructor property (apart from the obvious syntactic difference) is that instanceof inspects the object’s prototype chain.

So:

```
=> new Bar() instanceof Foo? true
=> new Bar() instanceof Bar? true
=> new Bar() instanceof Object? true
```

The above are all true.

Comment: My question is about the 2nd test "new Bar() instanceof Bar?".

Comment: ^^ `Bar.prototype === Foo` no, it is an instance of Foo.

Comment: new Bar() instanceof Bar? , yes and instanceof Object and instanceof Foo.  because Bar.prototype is an object instanceof Object will be true